# Need to assign an integer value to a sharedpreference getInt value

Tags: android

Here is the code i tried:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
int balance = sharedPreferences.getInt("balance", 0);
prefEditor.putInt(balance, balance1);
prefEditor.commit();
```

Comment: Do you want to save a int value to the editor?

Comment: It's not clear what you are logically trying to do here?

Comment: Yea, but there is and existing int value in the editor just wanna replace it with another int value

Comment: I have a sharedpreference value1 which is an integer, then i intend changing the value in sharedpreference value1 with another integer value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments beneath your question, I understand that you simply wish to update a value within sharedpreferences. Your first line is fine:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
```

This next line is then optional. Use it if you want to get at the existing value held under the key "balance" before you replace it. Otherwise it is not required and has no bearing on the 3rd line of code which replaces "balance" with a new value.

```
int balance = sharedPreferences.getInt("balance", 0);
```

Then I think your 3rd line should become:

```
prefEditor.putInt("balance", balance1);
```

That will replace the value held under the key "balance" with whatever value is held in balance1. Notice the quotes around "balance" that you did not have in your original code.